# Oracle Union All How are the results output

Tags: oracle, union, union-all

We have a situation where we are using a 3rd party tool (jitterbit) to output a file and we need the file to have the header row. So I was thinking that we could use a union all in the Oracle view that we use to generate the data for the file.

But my question is will Oracle always read the top query of the union first?

Here would be a very basic example of what i am looking for

```
  select 'user.CustomAttribute.Client'
         ,'user.Email'
         ,'user.customAttribute.alternateEmail'
  from dual 
  UNION ALL 
  Select c.client 
         ,c.email
         ,c.alt_email
  from contact
```

So would the top part with all the hard coded values always be returned first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push it down into a subquery and add a column to manage your explicit ordering

```
SELECT client, email, alt_email
FROM (
 select 'user.CustomAttribute.Client' client 
         ,'user.Email' email
         ,'user.customAttribute.alternateEmail' alt_email
          -- here we add an aid to ordering, 1 comes first
         , 1 displayorder
  from dual 
  UNION ALL 
  Select c.client 
         ,c.email
         ,c.alt_email
          -- here we add an aid to ordering, 2 comes after our header
         , 2 displayorder
  from contact    )
order by displayorder, client;
```

Comment: Great idea, I appreciate the feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee or no default order for such queries in Oracle. You can, however, manage the desired order if you use a sub-query, such as:

```
 select * from (select 'user.CustomAttribute.Client' as client 
     ,'user.Email' as email
     ,'user.customAttribute.alternateEmail' as alt_email
from dual 
UNION ALL 
Select c.client 
     ,c.email
     ,c.alt_email
from contact)
order by client, email, alt_email;
```

Read this link for more details: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2341048?tstart=0

Comment: You don't need a subquery here; you can have an order by after the two union branches, and refer to the column aliases from the first branch. But this won't put the first union branch results first in the result set, which seems to be what the OP wants. You'd need a dummy flag to make the subquery achieve anything, as in Michael Broughton's answer.